# ContactsContract not saving some data to contacts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts

I'm using ContactsContract to save a lot of data to contacts (I didn't really expect the second .apply{} to work, but hey, I tried). When the activity is launched, the only fields that contain the info i put in them are: First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Company, Title, Phone1-3 + their labels , email1 and 2 + their labels, and Notes.

This means i'm missing Prefix, Suffix, Nickname, IM handle and type, the entirety of home and work addresses, and both dates (birtdhay and anniversary). Of course, I frist tried with only the first .apply{}, but the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI).apply {
            type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, fullName)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, givenName)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, familyName)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PREFIX, prefix)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.SUFFIX, suffix)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME, nickname)

            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, homeEmail)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL, workEmail)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)

            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, cellPhone)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE, homePhone)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE, workPhone)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)

            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.IM_HANDLE, imHandle)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.IM_PROTOCOL, imProtocol)

            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, organization)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.JOB_TITLE, jobTitle)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL, website)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NOTES, notes)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, homeAddressStreetName)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, homeLocality)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, homeRegion)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, homePostalCode)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, homeCountry)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)

            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, birthday)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
        }.apply { 
            type = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET, workAddressStreetName)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY, workLocality)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION, workRegion)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE, workPostalCode)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY, workCountry)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
            
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, anniversary)
            putExtra(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_ANNIVERSARY)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use constants under `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.X` with `Intent.ACTION_INSERT`

The list of supported fields is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert#constants_1

So for example home address might be added like this:

```
putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "Contacts Lane 123, SomeCity, OM United States");
putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME);
```

But note you can't add multiple postal addresses with this.

The special [DATA constant](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert#DATA) is different, it allows you to add whatever data you want by specifying the value and mimetype:

```
  ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();

  ContentValues row1 = new ContentValues();
  row1.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
  row1.put(Organization.COMPANY, "Android");
  data.add(row1);

  // add more rows here if needed of any type

  intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Insert.DATA, data);
```